# Re-directing path based on params passed in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following two buttons in my index.html.haml:

```
= button_to t('payer_contracts.new_global_payer_contract'), new_payer_contract_path, {:class => 'btn pull-left', :method => 'get'}
= link_to t('payer_contracts.new_bpci_payer_contract'), new_payer_contract_path
```

As you can see they both go to `new_payer_contract_path`. How can I make it so that if the first button is clicked, I can send a param such as `new_payer_contract_path(new_global_payer_contract)` ?

The problem is: in my new.html.haml, both of them are rendering '`global_form`'. I want the first button to render global_form and the second button to render '`bpci_form`'

Here is the new.html.haml:

```
- content_for(:title, t('payer_contracts.page_titles.new'))

- content_for :article do
  .common-main-container
    %h1= t('payer_contracts.new_payer_contract')
    = render 'global_form'
```

In my payer_contracts_controller I have this so far:

```
def new

    @payer_contract = PayerContract.new(
         id: '',
         contract_name: '',
         contract_type: {
             id: '',
             code_key: '',
             display: '',
             code_group: ''
    },
         amount: '',
         stoploss_amount: '',
         stoploss_reimbursement_percentage: '',
         begin_date: '',
         end_date: '',
         timely_filing_days: '',
         payer: ''
    )
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), you can pass a `params` hash:

```
<%= button_to t('payer_contracts.new_global_payer_contract'), new_payer_contract_path, class: 'btn pull-left', method: :get, params: { x: "y" } %>
```

This creates a `hidden_field` inside the form that `button_to` creates, allowing you to pass `params[:x]` to your next action.

---

**Update**

As per your comments, you're getting the `params[:x]` variable in your controller.

You just have to use this in your `ActiveRecord` query call:

```
#view
-if params["x"] == "y"
  = render "global_form"
-else
  = render "bpci_form"
```

Comment: I added that button, and now I am trying to modify my views so that****:     -if new_payer_contract_path(params['y'])
      =render 'global_form'
    -else
      = render 'bpci_form'      **** but this is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the console log for when you click the button? Knowing which params are being sent is the most important thing here

Comment: Looks like it is saying: Parameters: {"x"=>"y" }